# Why not use a map of maps to store a weighted graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Weighted graphs are typically stored as an adjacency matrix or an adjacency list.

The biggest disadvantage of an adjacency matrix is that it occupies O(|V|^2) space whereas an adjacency list occupies O(|V| + |E|) space.

The biggest disadvantage of an adjacency list is that it queries in worst case O(|V|) time whereas an adjacency matrix queries in O(1) time.

But if we use a map of maps, does this not solve both the time and space problems? It would occupy O(|V| + |E|) space and query in O(1) time.

So why not use a map of maps?

Comment: Some designs use a map of maps to store a graph.  For example the graph design I use in my work stores the out edges of a vertex in a map keyed by destination and stores the vertices as a map keyed by index number.  For a detailed description of this design see https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/cGraph-Class-Design

Answer (score 0):

The same applies to non-weighted graphs - why use a list instead of a set? A map of sets would allow you to answer queries like "is there an edge from node *x* to node *y*" in constant time.

The answer is that you use a list when you don't *need* to be able to perform such queries, or other operations (such as removing a neighbour) which take linear time for a list. Many graph algorithms don't require testing the existence of edges, or removing edges; the only thing you need the adjacency list data structure for is usually to iterate over a node's neighbours, and a list (or array) is perfectly good for that.

Consider [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn%27s_algorithm), for some examples. The only thing they use the graph data structure for is some kind of loop like "for each of *u*'s neighbours *v*".* They do not need to do any operations where a map-of-maps would outperform a map-of-lists, so for algorithms like these, it makes more sense to use the map-of-lists data structure; it is simpler, smaller in memory, and more efficient to iterate over.

On the other hand, if you do want to query or remove edges in constant time, then an adjacency matrix can do that, and is a simpler (and smaller) data structure than a map-of-maps. So you would only use a map-of-maps if you really needed to iterate over a node's neighbours *and* also perform queries or edge removals. There are some algorithms like that, but most algorithms don't need both.

<sub>* Kahn's algorithm also removes edges, but it only ever removes the edge currently being visited. Since the position of the edge to be removed from the list is already known, removal from a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) can be done in constant time; or if an unordered [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) is used, removal can be done in constant time by swapping the current neighbour to the end of the array and then shortening the array by 1.</sub>

Comment: But what if the graph is dynamically changing over time, wouldn't then a matrix be slow, because a new one must be created and a list, because a resize over time need to be done?

Comment: @GeorgiPeev Reallocating lists (or sets or maps) that grow isn't generally something you need to worry about for asymptotic complexity because it can be amortised to an O(1) cost per element added. For matrices you can do the same ─ allocate a bigger one than you need and resize to e.g. the next power of 2 when needed ─ although the matrix takes O(n^2) space so this won't be O(1) per node added. If your graph has enough edges then growing the matrix may still come out to O(1) amortised per *edge* added. In practice you probably start knowing an upper bound for how many nodes you will have.